# sqlite transaction, database table is locked (c++)

Tags: c++, sqlite

I don't understand why this code shows me:

> database table is locked

when I try to delete the *_old table. I use this code to change the type of a table column dynamically.

This is my code:

```
sqlite3_exec(this->connection, "BEGIN TRANSACTION;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

string query = "ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " RENAME TO " + tableName + "_old;";
cout << "8 " << query << endl;
                    
if(sqlite3_exec(this->connection, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    error = 1;                  
query = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (";
for(int i = 0; i < (int)colName.size(); i++)
{
    query += colName.at(i) + " " + colType.at(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)primaryKey.size(); j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(colName.at(i).c_str(), primaryKey.at(j).c_str()) == 0)
        {
            query += " PRIMARY KEY ";
            break;
        }
    }
    query += " " + colParam.at(i);
    if(i < ((int)colName.size() - 1))
        query += ", ";              
}
query += ");";
cout << "9" << query << endl;           
if(sqlite3_exec(this->connection, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    error = 1;
                    
query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "_old;";
cout << "10" << query << endl;
if(sqlite3_exec(this->connection, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)             
    error = 1;
                        
query = "DROP TABLE " + tableName + "_old;";
cout << "11" << query << endl;
if(sqlite3_exec(this->connection, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    error = 1;
                            
cout << sqlite3_errmsg(this->connection) << endl;       
if(error > 0)
{
    query = "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;";
    cout << "12" << query << endl;
    if(sqlite3_exec(this->connection, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        error = 1;              
}
else
{
    query = "COMMIT TRANSACTION;";
    cout << "13" << query << endl;
    if(sqlite3_exec(this->connection, query.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        error = 1;      
}
```

Comment: in sql, things like table manipulation such as drop cannot normally be a part of a transaction

Comment: I tried to put the drop table query after the transaction commit but the error is the same

Comment: why do you bother continuing with the transaction when an error occurs?

Comment: have you checked so you don't have the table open from some tool or something? like DB browser or whatever you use?

Comment: Yes, I checked! I'm sure it isn't

Comment: you cannot typically rollback database engine errors

Comment: You don't stop after your first error and the `error` variable is always assigned to the same value. There is no way to easily find which sql statement is the cause of your error. You should update your code regarding that.

Comment: the error is after the drop table query, it's a test code, I know that I don't break all if other queries fails...but they finish sucesfully, it's a problem only the drop table code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved, there was some previous queries with open statement, I use this code to close all before drop the table

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=0;
while((stmt=sqlite3_next_stmt(this->connection,0))!=0)
{
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```